# powershell - unable to exclude folders during recursive copy

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and am running into a problem while trying to exclude certain directories during recursive copy. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

```
$Date = Get-Date
$Date = $Date.adddays(-1)

$destPath = "\\destination\test"
$srcPath = "H:\program files\symphony\Save"
$srcPathRemits = “H:\program files\symphony\files"
$destDrive = "X:"
$User = "user"
$Password = "password"

$exclude = @('H:\program files\symphony\files\Temp\*','H:\program files\symphony\files\Other\*','H:\program files\symphony\files\etc\*','H:\program files\symphony\files\ParsedXML\*')

$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive($destDrive, $destPath, $false, $User, $Password)

gci -recurse -path $srcPathRemits -Exclude $exclude | ? {!($_.psiscontainer) -AND $_.lastwritetime -gt $Date} | %  { write-host $_.fullname; Copy-Item -path $_.fullname -destination $destDrive} 
$net.RemoveNetworkDrive($destDrive,"true","true")
```

Comment: When you say you ran into a problem, could you be more specific?  Did you get an error message?  What was it?

Comment: Please mark the question answered when you get a chance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You didn't say what the problem was, but I'll assume that the directories (`$exclude`) were not properly excluded.  Try this instead, for the `gci` line:

```
Get-Item -Path H:\program files\symphony\files\* -Exclude Temp, Other, etc, ParsedXML | Get-ChildItem -recurse | ? {!($_.psiscontainer) -AND $_.lastwritetime -gt $Date} | %  { write-host $_.fullname; Copy-Item -path $_.fullname -destination $destDrive}
```

Comment: Hi David, You are correct in your assumption, the ($exclude) was not working. Your solution works perfectly! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Can we maintain the destination folder structure as of the source?? It copies all files to single Destination