# Copy Files and Folder wtih Change in Files

Tags: powershell

I have PowerShell piece of code and its working fine but with issue.

Here is my PowerShell code:

```
Copy-Item C:\inetpub\wwwroot\* -Exclude *.*/Temp \\192.168.10.46\database_backups\Application -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I want to modified this code to accomplish these things:

- Exclude `/Temp` Folder from each Application (currently there are more than 200 Applications configured)
- I want to continue on errors
- If it's possible, I would like to only copy files/folders that are changed since last run of the command.

Comment: Don't try to script it. Use robocopy.

Answer (score 0):

- check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13354497/3109264) for excluding directories in Copy-Item
- -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue will carry on through non-terminating errors, but if you hit a terminating error anywhere, you'll still need to handle it.
- you'll have to use a comparison on the `LastWriteTime` property and the current date, `Get-Date`. This can be accomplished with an IF or WHERE statement.

[RoboCopy is a good way to do this](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2010/11/copy-files-only-if-they-have-changed/), but it only looks at the files for changes, I'm not sure of a good method to track "***since last run of the command***".